# Ionic update $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

after a bit of Ionic, i am scratching my head with an odd behaviour:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.myvar="red";



$scope.update=function() {

    $scope.myvar="blue";
    console.log($scope.myvar)    //correctly displays 'blue'
}

$scope.showvar=function() {

    console.log($scope.myvar);     //always display 'red', even if the update function has run
}
```

})

If i run the update functions, inside of it i can see the correct updated value for the var.

But if i run the show function after having runned the update one, the value showed is the initial one 'red'.

What am i missing ?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you declaring another `$scope` somewhere?  That'd be the most obvious explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3625/)) and it works well.

Here is the code:

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="update()">
  update
  </button>
  <button ng-click="showvar()">
  show
  </button>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myvar="red";

  $scope.update=function() {

      $scope.myvar= $scope.myvar != "blue" ? "blue" : "red";
      console.log($scope.myvar)    //correctly displays 'blue'
  }

  $scope.showvar=function() {

      console.log($scope.myvar);     //always display 'red', even if the update function has run
  }
});
```

Check this and try to find the differences. Maybe you missed something.

Hope it will help.